# Iterating <a> & Typescript optimization

Tags: reactjs, typescript

A piece of code - I realize that:

- content in the div could be optimized with a loop
- typing in typescript is not necessarily correct

Can someone advanced help in refactoring?

---

```
type Status =
  | "no-status"
  | "active"
  | "hold"
  | "close"

  interface IState {
    status: Status;
  }

const Main: React.FC = ()=>{
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<IState>("no-status");
    return(
        <div>                
           <a href='#'  onClick={()=>setStatus("active")} >Active </a> 
           <a href='#' onClick={()=>setStatus("hold")} >Idle </a>
           <a href='#' onClick={()=>setStatus("close")}>Close </a>           
      </div>     
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you defined your state as interface with KEY status...

```
type Status =
  | "no-status"
  | "active"
  | "hold"
  | "close"

  interface IState {
    status: Status;
  }

const Main: React.FC = ()=>{
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<IState>({status: 'no-status'});
    return(
        <div>                
           <a href='#'  onClick={()=>setStatus({status: 'active'})} >Active </a> 
           <a href='#' onClick={()=>setStatus({status: 'hold'})} >Idle </a>
           <a href='#' onClick={()=>setStatus({status: 'close'})}>Close </a>           
      </div>     
    );
};
```

edit:

```
const iterateStatus: Status[] = ['active', 'hold', 'close'];
const Main: React.FC = ()=>{
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<IState>({status: 'no-status'});
    return (
      <div>
        {iterateStatus.map((status) => (
          <a href="#" onClick={() => setStatus({ status: status })}>{status}</a>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: yes, i know it's not good practise, so i created this ticket for help ;/

Comment: It's possible to iterate <a>, it's like repetitive now ?

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean by iterate a? i edited the code but not sure what you are looking for

Comment: Ok, now it's pretty good. Thank You - why Status have [] ? The useState don't show inheritance from another than IState?

Comment: u mean this: const iterateStatus: Status[]... this is array typeof Status